# Elastic Beanstalk, Certbot does not recognize port 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, apache2, lets-encrypt, elastic-beanstalk

I have very simple app running single index.php file on the elastic beanstalk, and now I tried to install https using Letsencrypt.

But unfortunately I keep geeting this error:

```
PluginError: Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.
Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.
```

Here is my zipped code.

[image]

Here is my .ebextensions/https.config  https://pastebin.com/WyGiZVXA
Here is my logs https://pastebin.com/TiCWwB5D

Here is my php http application.

[image]

Any help for me to setup lets encrypt on the Beanstalk? or does Beanstalk doesn't support this kind of feature?

Update:

After adding new Vhost for port 80, Now I got following error:

```
Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I just added virtual host for 80 and now I got Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port, any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got anwser for that.
The only thing I need to provide is VirtualHost for the 80 port. it will be something like this (.ebextensions/myconfig.config).

```
files:
    /etc/httpd/conf.d/default.conf:
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            <VirtualHost *:80>
                RewriteEngine On
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ovideo
                ServerName teahrm.id
            </VirtualHost>
```

I have made a note regarding it in my blog so other who wan to setup PHP application in the AWS elastic beanstalk can refer to it https://undebugable.blogspot.com/2019/07/setup-aws-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-to.html .